# node.js: password authentication failed for user "yashb"

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, knex.js, pg

> This Error Came Up When I Was Using The Command
> yarn knex migrate:latest

```
password authentication failed for user "yashb"
error: password authentication failed for user "yashb"
    at Parser.parseErrorMessage (E:\JavaScript\todoapp\server\node_modules\pg-protocol\src\parser.ts:369:69)
    at Parser.handlePacket (E:\JavaScript\todoapp\server\node_modules\pg-protocol\src\parser.ts:188:21)     
    at Parser.parse (E:\JavaScript\todoapp\server\node_modules\pg-protocol\src\parser.ts:103:30)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (E:\JavaScript\todoapp\server\node_modules\pg-protocol\src\index.ts:7:48)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at Socket.emit (node:domain:475:12)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:199:23)
```

Username For Postgres is 'postgres' But In Error It Is Showing My System Name

**Please Help Me To Solve This Issue I am Not Able To Get This...**

Comment: Hi Yash, can you share your knex configuration? (No need to share your actual password.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.